# Data loss during windows partitioning | Foremost and autopsy tools

Tags: data-recovery

I'm currently dealing with a loss of 320gb of data. 
During the installation of windows, I accidentally deleted a partition (currently in a "not allocated space" state) please see example picture.

I tried Autopsy and Foremost, but both are not detecting any data on this SATA HHD. 
Is there any advice to proceed with?

The disk is untouched and nothing has been done after that operation

[Stage of data loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN08U.png)

Comment: Carefully try testdisk (preferably on an image of the drive); I've had good results. With that said, you'll probably have better luck asking at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate partition table. To do that you have to find where your deleted partition(s) started with some hex editor, write down where they start and then create new partition table.

Your picture says you're under windows. If partition is windows then it will start like this (`hexdump -C` of first 8 bytes):

```
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20                           |.R.NTFS |
```

which you can use as search pattern.

I would advise to create new partition table under linux as you can quickly check your work with `mount`. Unless you have some magical tools for windows. You can use any live linux you like ([here is small list with desriptions](https://www.pcsuggest.com/best-linux-live-distro/)) even in virtual box.